# why can i use myob Odbc direct driver v7my with windows 7

Tags: odbc, driver, myob

why can i use myob Odbc direct driver v7my with windows 7, i have tried using the same odbc driver with XP and vista and it works fine.

please help me tnx.

Answer (score 5):

If you're running a 64bit version of Windows, then you need to make sure you run the 32-bit version of the ODBC control panel to get access.

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

However, need a bit more detail to find out if that's your problem.